# react pwa firebase notification not working in android

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

i'm using firebase for my react PWA push notification , I've got everything setup for web app firebase push notification. when I try requesting a notification to desktop it works perfectly but on android devices when I send notification, event hough Postman gives success and message ID and etc but nothing shows on the screen neither in use, nor in background.

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is the answer in your case but, I had the same problem (notifications worked on desktop and IOS devices but not on Android). My problem was that I had notifications turned off. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Chrome app and try this.

1. To the right of the address bar, tap More. Settings. List item
2. Tap SiteSettings. Notifications.
3. At the top, turn the setting on or off.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how you combined both firebase-messaging-sw.js and your service-worker.js